# Ordinary Differential Equations - Harmonic Oscillator Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*A 3kg mass is attached to a spring with spring coefficient k = 48N/m. The mass is initially 0.5m to the left of equilibrium and at rest when it is let go. If the friction is negligible, find the equation of motion of the spring, together with its amplitude, period, and frequency.*

Have no idea how to go about deriving the equation. Supposedly the solution is: **x(t) = 1/2 cos(4t)**

Would greatly appreciate any help with regards to the derivation of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Newton's Law, the equation of motion is $$-48x=3\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$ which is simple harmonic motion with $\omega^2=16$
Applying the intitial conditions gives you the solution. The amplitude is clearly $0.5$ and the period is $\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$

Answer (score 0):

Uou need to use Hooke's law and Newton's second law of dynamics to find equation of motion. First says that for your spring, force is given by

$F=-kx$

Therefore by Newton's Law:

$x''(t)=-\frac{k}{m}x(t)$

Do you know how to go from here?